# $http.post not working with header

Tags: angularjs, api, http

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to make an API request that requires authorization. I have included it in the header of the request, but it is still not working. Looking in the Chrome network tab, It shows that the method used is OPTIONS and not POST.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}]);

app.service('Api', function ($http) {
    return {
        post: function(token){
            $http.defaults.headers.post['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token
            $http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/profile/me').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data)
            })
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: Are you using CORS on your API?

Comment: Can you see the headers being sent in chrome debugger network tab?
Have you tried using a tool like chrome Postman extension and set the headers manually to see if the API responds with the correct content?

Comment: @BenBlack Yes my Api using CORS.

Comment: @MonsieurNinja When I sent a request with postman work it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing by "it's not working" you mean you're getting a 401. This is an issue with IIS and CORS. Whenever you have CORS enabled on your API some requests will send a preflighted OPTIONS request. The problem with this is that the OPTIONS request doesn't have your authentication headers and IIS wants those authentication headers, it doesn't find them so it responds with a 401. I ran into the same issue and found my fix in [this](https://evolpin.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/the-cors/) article. If you're using Integrated Mode for your API on IIS this fix will be easy. The important stuff from the link is below.

Create an IHttpModule:

```
public class CORSModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreSendRequestHeaders += delegate
        {
            if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                var response = context.Response;
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And then register it in your config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Authorization" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  <modules>
    <add name="CORSModule" type="CORSModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

What this does is creates an IHttpModule that runs before IIS's authorization (*only if you're in Integrated Mode, if you're in Classic Mode I haven't found a fix for this*), checks to see if it's an OPTIONS request and then allows it.

Hope this helps.